# Excel Interop - Copy a filtered worksheet to a different Excel instance

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, interop

Suppose I have the following Excel Interop objects declared:

```
    Dim ExcelToKeepHidden As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim SheetToCopy As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    ...
    Dim ExcelToShow As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
```

Basically, I'm keeping a hidden instance of Excel in the background (Which contains the sheet `SheetToCopy` - Where I keep doing all the nitty-gritty work away from the user's attention) and then, I have a button **Show Excel Sheet**, that, when the user clicks it, should take my `SheetToCopy` object and make a copy of it into the `ExcelToShow` application.

In other words, the original `SheetToCopy` stays in the `ExcelToKeepHidden` application for further manipulation, but the `ExcelToShow` will show a copy of the sheet at the time the user clicks the button.

So, my challenge is that I can't just use the `SheetToCopy.Copy()` method because the new sheet is in a completely different instance of Excel. Also, because of the kind of manipulations I'm doing, I can't just copy a range of cells because I've applied filters to it and so the `paste` functionality doesn't allow me to keep the formatting, etc.

Basically, the only solution I'm seeing is to make a copy of the sheet into a new workbook **in the same excel application**, then close it and then re-open it in the second excel application, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this??

Any thoughts??  (VB or C# code are perfectly fine)

Thanks!!!!)

Comment: Keeping the sheet hidden in the current instance of excel looks like a good solution to me. Use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to hide it when you need to activate, filter etc.

Comment: The only challenge is that the user may close the visible sheet / the instance of excel while the form is still running and that could cause problems... I figured by having two separate instances of Excel, whatever the user does, it doesn't affect the instance used by the form.

Comment: You can catch the event and do whatever is needed. Similarly, if you use an addIn you can capture the event of a file being opened, and make sure that the other sheet is loaded in the background. There is no 100% cure for user stupidity but you can capture a lot of expected actions.

Comment: I can see that that could work, but it just seems like a more difficult way to do this than even the copying, saving, re-opening logic I mentioned above that completely separates out the two processes. Thanks, though, for the thought!

Comment: I suppose without knowing more about what is being done it's hard to give really good advice. Can you not have a hidden sheet in the same workbook? If the user closes the main sheet presumably they don't care any more about what is happening in the background. Does that data need to be preserved? The "for further manipulation" doesn't tell me if this manipulation needs to continue after the main sheet is closed... But in general, the simplest solution that works is the best.

Comment: I do apologize - I guess it's hard to explain the situation fully - Basically, the user will keep using the userform and, at any time, may want a "snapshot" of the data at that moment as an excel sheet they may email out / save to their desktop / manipulate manually... Each snapshot must be separate from all the others since they may serve completely different purposes - Hence my logic of giving the user each snapshot in a new instance of Excel. Hope that makes a bit more sense...

Comment: No need to apologize. What if each snapshot was a new sheet in the same workbook?... With a "paste special... values", you can preserve the status "as it was at this time". You could hide the sheets, and give an option to "look at an old snapshot" by offering a list of all the hidden sheets which you tagged as snapshot sheets.

Comment: Again, a pretty cool (and logical) idea... I'm just thinking I'd rather  go the way of the separate applications if at all possible, though. Thanks for your continued help / thoughts!!

Comment: You have to feel comfortable with your solution... I'm just giving my thoughts, and some possible alternatives. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to my own question (in case anyone else faces a similar issue).

Although you can't use the following to paste the data across two applications:

```
RangeWeWant.Copy()
NewSheet.Range(RangeWeWant.Address).PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats)
NewSheet.Range(RangeWeWant.Address).Value = RangeWeWant.Value
```

Since the `Range.PasteSpecial` module will throw an error, the `Sheet.PasteSpecial` does not!

So this code did work for me:

```
RangeWeWant.Copy()
NewSheet.Range(RangeWeWant.Address).Range("A1").Select()
NewSheet.PasteSpecial(Format:="Microsoft Excel 8.0 Format")
NewSheet.Range(RangeWeWant.Address).Value = RangeWeWant.Value
```

I know this is a simple solution, but it did the trick perfectly!!!

Hope this helps someone else too!!